# TeamBuild - Best way to divide Project output

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a teambuild setup that builds a solution that has several projects in it.  When the build is done all the binaries are lumped in to a single location.

Is there a good way to get these to go in project specific folders?  (Similar to what you get when you build in Visual Studio?)

Example:

```
MySolution
   |
   +-> Project 1
   |
   +-> Project 2
   |
   +-> Project 3
   |
   +-> Project 4
```

Right now TeamBuild gives me this by default:

```
Binaries
   |
   +-> Project1.exe, Project2.exe, Project3.exe, Project4.exe, Project1Support.dll, Project2Support.dll, Project3Support.dll, Project4Support.dll
```

What I want is:

```
Binaires
   |
   +-> Project 1
   |     |
   |     +->Project1.exe
   |     |
   |     +->Project1Support.dll
   |
   +-> Project 2
   |     |
   |     +->Project2.exe
   |     |
   |     +->Project2Support.dll
   |
   +-> Project 3
   |     |
   |     +->Project3.exe
   |     |
   |     +->Project3Support.dll
   |
   +-> Project 4
         |
         +->Project4.exe
         |
         +->Project4Support.dll
```

Do I have to manually copy each file around?  Is there an easier way?  (I hope so.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaron Hallberg has a great post on this exact scenario [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/archive/2007/06/07/preserving-output-directory-structures-in-orcas-team-build.aspx).

If you're going to be plowing through as much TFSBuild customization as I have done recently, you may want to check out the rest of his blog as well.